# KQL query to search in multiple fields in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created this KQL which is working fine, I am searching for a string `error` in the `message` field and the same field should not contain `EOF`. Here I used must and must not. Now I want to add an extra condition(AND) where a field(kubernetes.pod.name) contains `test`.

```
{
      "size": 1,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "message": {
                  "query": "error",
                  "operator": "OR",
                  "prefix_length": 0,
                  "max_expansions": 50,
                  "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                  "lenient": false,
                  "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                  "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "from": "now-10000m",
                  "to": null,
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "message": {
                  "query": "EOF",
                  "slop": 0,
                  "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative": true,
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      "sort": [
        {
          "@timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: BTW, KQL is short for [Kibana Query Language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html) and what you've got above is a DSL (Domain Specific Language) query, not KQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply extend the `must` array with a `match` query to apply one more logical AND:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "kubernetes.pod.name": "test"       <--
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "message": {
              "query": "error",
              ...
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": {
              "query": "EOF",
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. When I removed the newly added block. I see the logs with kubernetes.pod.name: test-XXXXX. 

Also when I replace the value in the new block from test to test-XXXXX. I see the logs. So I guess it's not checking the contains but the exact string

Comment: Whats the mapping of that field?

Comment: "mappings" : {
      "kubernetes.pod.name" : {
        "full_name" : "kubernetes.pod.name",
        "mapping" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 1024
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Thanks -- yea that's what I thought -- a keyword mapping only supports full, exact matches. You've got 2 options: reindex everything as `text` + `keyword` as a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) or use a [`prefix` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) or even a `regexp` query.

Comment: I used regexp but it's not working. How I can reindex ?

Comment: Read [this guide](https://www.lewuathe.com/how-to-reindex-elasticsearch.html) first and then use the [es-dump utility](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump).

Comment: Ah. Actually, Filebeat continuously sending logs. So I can't always update the dumps. Can I use Prefix query without reindexing?

Comment: Same as above but replace `match` with `prefix`!

Comment: update the question with the full mapping please. The one you provided doesn’t look right. Also what ES ver are you on ?